# Swift 2 downcasting

Tags: swift2

My intent is to pass returningClass as an argument to this piece of code.  I am receiving the compiler error -- 'returningClass' not a type.  When I substitute MedicationsViewController for returningClass after as?, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == screenParameters.addSequeDoneName {
let returningClass: AnyObject.Type = MedicationsViewController.self
if let destinationVController = segue.destinationViewController              as? returningClass {            
        }}
}
```

Comment: If you know the returningClass 's type why are u using AnyObject.Type in first place .    Use let returningClass : MedicationsViewController

Comment: The idea is to return control to a viewController that is on the navigation controller stack.  My objective is to pass an argument that can be used after as?.  I only used the let statement to illustrate the problem, i.e., to make the problem more comprehensible.

Comment: I understand this, but the thing is the segue.destinationViewController  has to be casted into the type (to what it is i.e. what the destinationViewController type is ) than it should not have any problem , your segue goes currently to MedicationsViewController and that is why putting that after as? works , when your case would be different , when your segue would take you to different destinationViewController , putting that after  as? will definitely work .

Comment: Are you suggesting the statement: let returningClass = MedicationsViewController.self.  If so, I received the same error message.  As you can probably tell, I am relatively new to Swift2/IOS.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: let me suggest you something ,try this you want to return view controller that is on navigation controller stack ,let returningClass = gettheviewcontrollerfromnavigationstack () , (I.e. Not a real function use one that gives you the result as what it's name suggest ) .

Comment: Since I am using StoryBoard, I actually don't create the viewController on the navigation stack.  That is why I use self.  I don't know why returningClass = MedicationsViewController.self doesn't work.  The error message is the same: 'returningClass' not a type.  When I print to console returningClass, it gives me "MedicationsViewController" as you would expect.